# Moving a resource from an active directory to another within the same subscription

Tags: powershell, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-group

I have an Azure resource group under an Active Directory AC1 which I would like to move to another active directory AC2 within the same subscription. How can I achieve this using UI or powershell (or any other means)? To make thing easier I can forget all about the resource group itself and just for the sake of argument lets say I have a resource R1 in AC1 which I would like to move to AC2 within the same subscription.

How can I do this *without recreating the resource* in the destination directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, given the way information is presented in Azure Portal one is led to believe that an Azure Subscription contains one or more Azure ADs which is not correct. From [`https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory/`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory/):

> Every Azure subscription has a trust relationship with an Azure AD
>   instance. This means that it trusts that directory to authenticate
>   users, services, and devices. Multiple subscriptions can trust the
>   same directory, but a subscription trusts only one directory.

So to answer your question, you can move resources from one Azure Subscription to another provided both Subscriptions use same Azure AD as trust store. There's no automated way of moving resources from one Azure Subscription which trusts one Azure AD to a different Azure Subscription which trusts a different Azure AD.